# Check Valid or not

Tags: reactjs, validation

I am beginner so I have to check if my code is valid or not. so I have to push the message to array so that I can take the length of array then if it is more than 0 then navigate it to other page. But when I am trying to push message to array then also array is empty.
Here is my code-

```
 const validate = (values) => {
    let errors = [];
if(!values.email){
    errors.email="Email is Missing"
    errors.push(errors.email)
} else if(!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)){
    errors.email="Invalid Email"
    errors.push(errors.email)
}
return errors;
```

}
export default validate

Comment: why do you first set email prop then push ?
if you wanna define email property then your errors variable must be object , not an array

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake where you wrote : `errors.email` - your `errors` suppossed to be a simple **array** which contains string messages, it's **not** an object with some `email` field.

All you need to do is simply put the string message directly between the `( )` of `push` and this will push it to the array.

Code:

```
const validate = (values) => {
  let errors = [];
  if(!values.email){
    errors.push("Email is Missing")
  } 
  else if(!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(values.email)){
    errors.push("Invalid Email")
  }
return errors;
```